# Java thread start() without join() or interrupt() in servlet

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I have a servlet filter that carries some logic and produces output before a request is served by it's primary page. I have a new need to send out the output a few seconds later than at the moment it is generated (with ~10s delay). Because of certain poor design choices made earlier I can't move the position of the filter just to have the output sent after.

I've chosen to spawn off a thread and delay transmission of the message in there. I'm currently not taking any explicit steps to halt execution of this thread. I'm not sure if everything is getting cleaned up properly though. Should I be using join() or interrupt() or any other Thread methods to clean up safely after this?

So within the main servlet code I have something like this...

```
Thread t = new Thread(new MessageSender(message, 10000));
t.start();
//Carry on.. la la la
```

While there are other fields in this class, I just stripped out a lot of the non-essential stuff like making DB connections etc to make the point clear.

```
private static class MessageSender implements Runnable {
    String message;
    int delay;

    public MessageSender(String message, int delay) {
        this.message = message;
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
            System.out.println(new java.util.Date() + ": hello world");                
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Do blah
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Do blah blah
        } finally {
            // Close connections and stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code should be fine, the VM will clean up the thread once it completes.

However, I'd advise not using raw threads like that, but instead using a `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService`, creating using `java.util.concurrent.Executors`. It's a nicer abstraction that would better control your thread allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, everything will be properly cleaned up. Thread dies after finishing run() method and as you have no more references to that thread object - it will be properly garbage-collected.

Just be sure that "Thread t" object will not be referenced by anything. To be sure on that, you can use:
(new Thread(...)).start();

Answer (score 1):

The servlet specification explicitly states (section "Thread safety") that request and response objects are not guaranteed to be thread-safe, and that if those objects are handed off to other threads, then the application is responsible for ensuring that these objects are synchronized and that they are accessed only within the scope of the servlet's service method.  In other words, you must .join() those threads.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had to answer the same question myself :)

I can acknowledge that the threads are indeed cleaned up after they complete. If you're not completely certain the spawned threads ever die, you should be able to monitor the process and see how many threads it's currently running at. If the number keeps growing, something's outta control.

On a Unix-system, you can use the `ps` command, but I'm rusty, so I asked google instead of reading the man-page.
One of the first hits on google was [This script that lists threads for each process](http://www.embedded-linux.co.uk/tutorial/list_threads). Output looks like this

```
PID TID CLS RTPRIO  STAT    COMMAND WCHAN
....
16035   16047   TS  -   S   (java)  
16035   16050   TS  -   S   (java)  
16035   16054   TS  -   S   (java)  
16035   16057   TS  -   S   (java)  
16035   16058   TS  -   S   (java)  
16035   16059   TS  -   S   (java)  
16035   16060   TS  -   S   (java)  
....
```

And I just `grep` the output for the process id (pid) of the process I want to watch and count the number of lines, each one corresponding to a thread. Like this:

```
morten@squeeze: ~$ sh /tmp/list_threads.sh | grep 16035 | wc -l
20
```

So the program I'm currently watching (PID 16035) has 20 threads running.

This required no knowledge of `jconsole` or any changes to the code. The last part is probably the most important part, as I haven't written the program myself, so now I don't have to read and understand the program.